# Microsoft Exchange 2007, give limited access to user to manage contacts?

Tags: exchange-2007, contacts, exchange

We have a global contact list (external people [clients]) in our Exchange 2007 and we in the IT are thinking to give a limited access to selected user(s) [marketing & reception] to go and manage only the contact list (names, phones, address, AD groups, etc) and nothing more.

What is the best approach to make it happen without losing the security measures and make it as easy as possible for them (they are not IT)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you'd be able to create a security group, add marketing & reception to that group, then give it change rights to those contacts (or their container).